# Ubuntu 20.04 logging in, stuck on purple screen

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, fcitx

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) on my 2014 13" MacBook Pro. First, when I use USB stick install Ubuntu 20, everything is okay. After the installation, system can be normally use also okay. When i changed input method from `ibus` to `fcitx` and restart, after the logging in, stuck on purple screen or sometimes black screen. What i did wrong?

Comment: Maybe change it back to `ibus`?

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem, but i want to use `sogoupinyin` which is using for input Chinese chars, it depends `fcitx`, but if i changed input method to `fcitx`, appear this problem.

Comment: Of course, sorry for my snarky comment. I wouldn't know where to start debugging this error. Maybe you could look at the output of `sudo journalctl`?